# Antd Sidebar Height Responsive in ReactJs

Tags: reactjs, antd, sidebar

So I am working with antd Sider and Menu trying to create a Sidebar with responsive height. I have researched alot of it and tries some solutions but none of them worked.
Solutions I have tried:
setting minHieght of sider to 100vh
setting minHieght of layout to 100vh
using percentages to define height in above cases
also tried to give menu height of 100vh

I have attached Screenshots for the code Current View of sidebar,Sidebas.js, Sidebar.scss, Page I want to call this component

[image: Current View]

[image: Sidebr.js]

[image: Sidebar.scss]

[image: File in which component is called]

Comment: try to find the original class of the antd component and change the className style from a wrapper tag in css

Answer (score 0):

You should get this class names for your changes.

```
ant-menu ant-menu-root
```

[image]